# What is the cleanest to completely exit a locust process if test prerequisites fail?

Tags: python, locust

I have an 'on_test_start' hook that tests for the existence of some environmental variables before the test starts:

```
@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(**_kwargs):
    env_vars_present = check_vars.check_existence_of_env_vars(["VAR1", "VAR2"])
    if not env_vars_present:
        sys.exit()
```

This works, but I don't like using `sys.exit()` which is a rather dirty way to quit a process. Is there a better alternative? I've tried raising an exception, but this doesn't stop the runners. I've also tried `environment.runner.quit()`. This quits the runners, but locust process continues until run-time limit is reached. What's the cleanest way to exit the process if some prerequisite checks fail? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea with `environment.runner.quit()` you just need to have that happen on the master, not the workers. You need the workers to communicate the failure to the master and then the master can can quit, which will stop the master and all the workers.

You could either use other Event Hooks like [request](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request) with a custom Name you could check a failure for, [report_to_master](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.report_to_master) to add in some extra data to the report payload sent to the master that you could check for its existence and quit on. Both of those you'd use worker_report on the master to trigger your check and quit. Doing it this way could help you get these steps in any test output data so you could clearly see what the problem was without doing much custom reporting work.

Or along the same lines but maybe slightly cleaner and more direct would be to use the [communication between nodes](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-distributed.html#communicating-across-nodes) to have the workers send a message directly to the master and have the master quit when that message was received. Code would look something like this:

```
@events.init.add_listener
def quit_env_failure_message(environment, **_kwargs):
    global ENV
    ENV = environment
    if isinstance(environment.runner, MasterRunner):
        environment.runner.register_message('env_failure', quit_on_env_failure)


def quit_on_env_failure(msg, **kwargs):
    ENV.runner.quit()


@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(**_kwargs):
    env_vars_present = check_vars.check_existence_of_env_vars(["VAR1", "VAR2"])
    if not env_vars_present:
        environment.runner.send_message('env_failure')
```

Doing it this way, you may need to do extra work to get whatever kind of tests result reporting you'd want. That would most likely go in `quit_on_env_failure()`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But it does seem like a lot of work to accomplish something very simple, as well as hard to understand unless you understand locust architecture. Do you think it's a reasonable candidate for a feature request? Checking test prereqs seems before test execution seems like a common use case that could be simplified

Comment: Of course you always put in a feature request. But I'm not sure it's that common of a situation. The idea behind Locust is to replicate client side behavior, with those needing simple HTTP calls being the core demographic. Lots of features have been added to enable more complex scenarios. Even so, are two extra functions for sending a pre-test failure from worker to master that difficult? Maybe, but I'm not sure. Perhaps it's more of a documentation problem?